# Advantage Database connection string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, connection-string, advantage-database-server

Does anyone know the right format of the connection string required to connect to the Advantage Database in PowerShell? what even is the driver that needs to be used?

I cant even find any documentation relating to the advantage database, so if anyone has a link to that, I would be very grateful.

EDIT:

I have this code now:

```
$connectionString = "Driver={Advantage ODBC Driver};Data Source=xxx;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
```

and it produces this error:

```
[14:45] Greg Skrzypczak
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [08001] [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage ODBC Driver]Unable to connect"

At line:4 char:1

+ $connection.Open()

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OdbcException
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something or have got something wrong...
I know ODBC driver is set up correctly as other services use it without a hickup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it, posting solution as it might help others:

instead of 3 lines of code all is needed, before opening connection, is:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("DSN=NameOfDSNiWantToUSe")
```

Answer (score 0):

For `ODBC` you could try with

```
$connectionString = "Driver={Advantage ODBC Driver};Data Source=myServerAddress;Catalog=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

# Perform database operations

$connection.Close()
```

Or for `OLE DB`

```
$connectionString = "Provider=Advantage.OLEDB;Data Source=myServerAddress;Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

# Perform database operations

$connection.Close()
```

Comment: Hi, I have edit my question with the code i have and error it gives, any ideas?